# Why isn't this P-MOSFET switch circuit working?

Tags: switching

I've been using the FDN304P coupled with an ESP32 to cut 3.3 V or 5 V with this circuit.

I'll focus on the 3.3 V MOSFET.

Schematic:

[image]

PCB layout:

[image]

**The problem**

When the display connector is detached, I can see the drain going high and low, but going low takes 3 ms.

CH1 is IO4, CH2 is display.pin12:

[image]

[image]

NOTICE: the time divider.

When I attach the display connector to the display it seems I can't drive the pin low anymore.

[image]

It just always stay high.

There must be something on the other side keeping pin12 high, but I'm not sure what.

Here is a pic:

[image]

---

The previous version of this PCB just had IO4 connected directly to display.pin12. It had some quirks, but worked fine.

Anyway, the same problem happens also on the 5 V MOSFET which has this schematic. That leads me to think I'm doing something wrong.

[image]

Comment: What is the pin used for on the display module? Is there a data sheet and pinout available? Because this is all up to the display.

Comment: hey @Justme i cant really find the datasheet this is the nspanel-us product from sonoff. It should be this https://nextion.tech/datasheets/nx4832f035/ pin 3 is attached to an STM32G031G8 pin PA7 which apparently is just I/O

Comment: It tells nothing what the pin is and why do you need to control it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *When the display connector is detached, I can see the drain going high
> and low, but going low takes 3 ms.*

When the MOSFET isn't activated it acts like an open circuit so, the time it takes for the output voltage to discharge is largely determined by the input resistance of the oscilloscope probe (possibly 1 MΩ to 10 MΩ).

3 ms sounds very reasonable under these circumstances.

> *When I attach the display connector to the display it seems I can't
> drive the pin low anymore.*

Let's me be clear; the MOSFET can only pull that pin to a high-state. In other words it cannot drive that line low so, if there is an internal pull-up resistor in the display, the pin will remain high.

> *The previous version of this PCB just had IO4 connected directly to
> display.pin12. It had some quirks, but worked fine.*

That confirms my suspicion; you should probably use an external pull-up and low-side N channel MOSFET or, stick with the IO pin driving it directly.

> *the same problem happens also on the 5 V MOSFET which has this
> schematic*

Following a discussion in comments with @6v6gt, it appears that the ESP32 is powered from 3.3 volts. This means that it can never properly deactivate MOSFET Q1 because its source is at 5 volts (leaving 1.7 volts from gate to source). This is enough to keep the MOSFET at least partially activated. You should look for a circuit change to fix this.

Comment: thanks @Andy aka, what about the other circuit though? the 5v mosfet driving a presence sensor.

Comment: @AndreaBaccega I suspect that IO17 is remaining high and this bleeds through the chip and keeps it powered in an unconventional and undesirable way. This is quite common to see with many ICs. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: @AndreaBaccega Also, you are using a 3.3v device (ESP32) to drive the gate of a P Channel mosfet which, itself, is controlling a 5 volt circuit. You will have difficulty switching the PMOS off. Even if you set pinmode() to input on the ESP32 pin, any pin protection diodes may hold the voltage below 5 volts and, hence, keep the PMOS on. Ideally, you use a high side switch configuration which requires the addition of an NPN transistor (or N Channel mosfet). Search for "high side switch"

Comment: @6v6gt that's a very good point. I assumed that the ESP32 is powered from 5 volts but, if this isn't the case then it's a bad design.

Comment: It is definitely so that the ESP32 pins are 3.3v so the circuit design has to be updated. Maybe you can update your answer to include this use case.

Comment: @6v6gt yes I will.

Comment: thanks for all the reply. What circuit would you then suggest? for the display i need to make sure the pin goes either 3v3 or gnd original board used an S8050 transistor apparently?

And for the 5v?

Comment: @AndreaBaccega as a new site user you may think that SE is like a forum where questions can evolve and twist and turn. Actually, there comes a point where a line needs to be drawn under any question and answer and, we are at this point. So, if you can't find a suitable circuit I suggest you raise a brand-new question and take note of the link I posted in an earlier comment.